# Inflate two layouts in getView() to implement ListView Section header

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to create section headers for my `ListView` in a way that some list rows have headers and some do not. So what i have is three xml layout files. `fragment_listview.xml` contains the `<ListView>`

`row_listview.xml` contains the content for `ListView` rows

`header_listview.xml` is for the section headers.

`Feeds.java` is my model class.

So in my adapter i have something like this:

```
public class FeedsArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Feeds> {

private Context context;
private List<Feeds> feeds;
private LayoutInflater vi;

FeedsArrayAdapter(Context c, List<Feed> ff){ //initializes all the class member fields }

public void getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    Feeds f = feeds.get(position);
    if(f.headerNeeded()){

       convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.header_listview, null);
       TextView textViewHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feed_header);

       textViewHeader.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(feed.date));
   }
   else {
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_listview, null);

        TextView textViewfeedHeading = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feed_heading);
        TextView textViewfeedSubheading = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feed_subheading);
        TextView textViewfeedDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);
        ImageView imageViewfeedIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feed_icon);
        ImageView imageViewfeedBanner = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feed_banner);

        textViewfeedHeading.setText(feed.title);
        textViewfeedSubheading.setText(feed.subtitle);
        textViewfeedDate.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(feed.date));

    }

    return convertView;
 }
```

So this gives us something like this:

```
---header1----
---header2----
___Row 3_____
___Row 4_____
```

What i want is:

```
-----header 1------
_____Row 1_______
-----header 2------
_____Row 2_______
_____Row 3_______
_____Row 4_______
```

If i try to inflate `row.listview` in `if(true)` I get an exception.

Any approach how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Sticky Header Library [here](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders)

Answer (score 0):

`yourListView.addHeaderView(yourHeaderView);`

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29

Comment: This is not what OP is asking.

Answer (score -1):

use expandable listview with BaseExpandableAdapter